# Sorting a hash where keys contain non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, natural-sort

I have a hash like the following:

```
my %hash=( '(293 to 296)'   => 2,
           '(3118 to 3121)' => 2,
           '(330 to 333)'   => 2,
           '(2126 to 2129)' => 2,
           '(1999 to 2002)' => 2,
           '(2138 to 2141)' => 9,
           '(771 to 774)'   => 4,
           '(2016 to 2019)' => 1,
           '(888 to 891)'   => 5,
           '(3102 to 3105)' => 1,
        );
```

I want to sort my hash using keys, where keys contains brackets. I have tried the following code,

```
foreach $key(sort {$b <=> $a} keys %hash)
{
    print $key;
}
```

and I got the following, which is not numerically sorted:

> (888 to 891)(2016 to 2019)(293 to 296)(3118 to 3121)(3102 to 3105)(330
>   to 333)(1999 to 2002)(2126 to 2129)(2138 to 2141)(771 to 774)

I expect an output, which is numerically sorted as below. Please suggest me a way to achieve the following:

```
(293 to 296)
(330 to 333)
(771 to 774)
(888 to 891)
(1999 to 2002)
(2016 to 2019)
(2126 to 2129)
(2138 to 2141)
(3102 to 3105)
(3118 to 3121)
```

Comment: What if the ranges overlap? Should you sort on start, end, or median?

Comment: Ithnk what you are looking for is "[natural sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/natural-sort)" - for which there is even a tag here on SO. I have added it to the question. See the reponses by myself and @Borodin for examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` works by passing `$a` and `$b` into a function, and returning `-1`, `0` or `+1`.

The simplest - sorting on the first number - would go like this:

```
sort { $a =~ s/.(\d+).*/$1/r <=> $b =~ s/.*(\d+).*/$1/r } keys %hash
```

This extracts the first numeric value from each key, compares and returns that comparison value.

Of course, if your ranges overlap, this won't work the way you want - you'll have to get a bit more complicated - if you have:

100 to 200
   150 to 180 
   120 to 205

How should they be sorted? Either way though - you write a subroutine that 'works' on `$a` and `$b` and performs the comparison. A useful trick  here is that the 'standard' sort operators - `<=>` and `cmp` - return zero, and thus can be shortcutted with `||`.

So:

```
sub compare_numbers {
   my @a = $a =~ m/(\d+)/g;
   my @b = $b =~ m/(\d+)/g; 
   return ( $a[0] <=> $b[0] 
         || $a[1] <=> $b[1] )
}
```

If the first comparison is zero, then the second is evaluated.

Or you can calculate the intermediate value:

```
sub compare_numbers {
   my @a = $a =~ m/(\d+)/g;
   my @b = $b =~ m/(\d+)/g; 
   return ( ($a[1] - $a[0] / 2 + $a[0]) <=> ($b[1] - $b[0] / 2 + $b[0])
}
```

You would use either of these in a similar way to above:

```
sort compare_numbers keys %hash
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i cannot understand the subroutine part. How does it work? and how can we implement for my input? Your assistance will greatly help me to understand the process.

Comment: sort compare_numbers keys %hash

Comment: It's kinda clunky to use `s///r` to remove everything except the digits that you want

Comment: @Borodin But it's sure nice to have `/r` !!

Comment: @G.Cito: It's one of the nicer enhancements I agree. But remember that it's available only in Perl v5.14 or better. There's a troubling number of v5.8 installations out there

Answer (score 2):

`'(293 to 296)'` isn't a number (and doesn't even begin with a number) so trying to sort it numerically doesn't make any sense.

You could extract the first number from it and sort on that.

```
($a) = ($a =~ /(\d+)/);
($b) = ($b =~ /(\d+)/);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that a string like `(293 to 296)` has no numerical value. If you had `use warnings 'all'` in place as you should, you would have seen multiple warnings like

> Argument "(293 to 296)" isn't numeric in sort

and every key evaluates to zero so they are all equal as far as `sort` is concerned

So you have to extract a number from each value to be used in a numerical sort. I would just snag the lower limit of each range and sort by that.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my %hash = (
    '(293 to 296)'   => 2,
    '(3118 to 3121)' => 2,
    '(330 to 333)'   => 2,
    '(2126 to 2129)' => 2,
    '(1999 to 2002)' => 2,
    '(2138 to 2141)' => 9,
    '(771 to 774)'   => 4,
    '(2016 to 2019)' => 1,
    '(888 to 891)'   => 5,
    '(3102 to 3105)' => 1,
);

my @keys = sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) = map /(\d+)/, $a, $b;
  $aa <=> $bb;
} keys %hash;

say for @keys;
```

#### output

```
(293 to 296)
(330 to 333)
(771 to 774)
(888 to 891)
(1999 to 2002)
(2016 to 2019)
(2126 to 2129)
(2138 to 2141)
(3102 to 3105)
(3118 to 3121)
```

This could be made even more concise by using the `nsort_by` function from [`List::MoreUtils`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) or [`List::UtilsBy`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy) like this

```perl
use List::MoreUtils 'nsort_by';

say for nsort_by { /(\d+)/ and $1 } keys %hash;
```

The output from this code is identical to that of the above

Comment: I'm starting to remember to like `and` - very neat and tidy ++  Can you explain how the `m//` and the `and` cooperate?

Comment: OT: I hope some of the choice functions from `List::UtilsBy` get moved  into `List::Utils`.  `Sort::Naturally` (see my answer) does what it says on the tin, but it would be nice if an `nsort` routine came in the box with one of the .Dual Life modules.

Comment: The `and` operator works as a *shortcut*. It returns the left-hand operand if it is *true*, otherwise the right-hand operand. In this case `/(\d+)/` should always be *true* so `and` returns the captured string. If there happens to be a key value that contains no decimal digits then the `and` will evaluate to the empty string. It may be nicer to use `/(\d+)/ ? $1 : 0` so that the result is always a number, but you must decide how you want to handle malformed keys

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In below script i used pattern matching to remove the `( )` with `/r` flag. 
It helps to hold the original data from the substitution. Then it will sort numerically.

```
my %hash=( '(293 to 296)'   => 2,
           '(3118 to 3121)' => 2,
           '(330 to 333)'   => 2,
           '(2126 to 2129)' => 2,
           '(1999 to 2002)' => 2,
           '(2138 to 2141)' => 9,
           '(771 to 774)'   => 4,
           '(2016 to 2019)' => 1,
           '(888 to 891)'   => 5,
           '(3102 to 3105)' => 1,
        );



foreach my $i (sort { $a=~s/\(//rg <=> $b=~s/\(//rg }  keys %hash)
{
    print "$i\n";

}
```

Comment: Is that going to work given you have non numeric values in there still?

Comment: @Sobrique Yes it work.  For example consider the `$a = "10 to 15";
 print int($a)+14; ` It give result as 24. Because of the int function. As the same way it works because of the numeric comparison operator. If my explanation is wrong can you please explain what is wrong?  I got it from practically., can you please share what is the reason behind this. Thank you.

Comment: @mkhun   @Sobrique so, but,  *why* does this work? The numeric comparison operator `<=>` gives parsing hints to the compiler (by design or by accident)? And somehow the non-destructive substitution (`/r`) of non-numeric non-alphabetic, non-existing characters surrounded by `()` using `|` to alternate just magically sorts in a quasi-"natural" way?  I think I prefer doing it on purpose as in the response by @Borodin or my own  ... +1 anyway but if this didn't seem magical to me I might like it more :-)

Comment: @mkhun what is | doing in the s/\(|\)//rg ? Is it choosing either/or ( and ) for replacement? Or something more magical?

Comment: False alarm ... `s/[\(\)]//r` works just as well. For some small font, typo related reasons it wasn't working when I posted those comments.

Comment: @G.Cito Thank you for your comment.  It  `s/\(//` is enough for to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the CPAN modules that "naturally" sorts values (*e.g.*  you could use [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Natrually)).

This would sort of hide what is going on though. So for educational purposes I like [`@Sobrique`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique), [`@Borodin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) and [`@Quentin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)'s explanations.

```
use Sort::Naturally;
my @nsorted ;
@nsorted = nsort ( <DATA> ) ;
print @nsorted;

__DATA__
(293 to 296)
(3118 to 3121)
(330 to 333)
(2126 to 2129)
(1999 to 2002)
(2138 to 2141)
(771 to 774)
(2016 to 2019)
(888 to 891)
(3102 to 3105)
```

**Output:**

```
(293 to 296)
(330 to 333)
(771 to 774)
(888 to 891)
(1999 to 2002)
(2016 to 2019)
(2126 to 2129)
(2138 to 2141)
(3102 to 3105)
(3118 to 3121)
```

Comment: I don't know but maybe a lot of sorting can just be done [naturally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEOIiIaJoPg) ... with "finesse and grace".